# MySQL error 1054: Unknown column 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_CUSTOM_FIELDS' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

I am using ZenCart with a client and have an issue. I am basically copying one of his websites to the other but have the following error.

Any help would be great,

Thanks.

```
MySQL error 1054: Unknown column 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_CUSTOM_FIELDS' in 'field list'
When executing:
INSERT INTO kyk_products SET
                        products_model                  =   'Beauty 01 pink' ,
                        products_price                  =   '54.95' ,
                        products_image                  =   'BEAUTY-01L-BPSAT.jpg' ,
                        products_weight                 =   '0' ,
                        products_tax_class_id           =   '' ,
                        products_date_available         =   '' ,
                        products_date_added             =   '2011-09-13 10:05:22' ,
                        products_last_modified          =   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
                        products_quantity               =   '100' ,
                        master_categories_id            =   '9' ,
                        manufacturers_id                =   '1',
                        products_status                 =   '0',
                        metatags_title_status           =   '0',
                        metatags_products_name_status   =   '0',
                        metatags_model_status           =   '0',
                        metatags_price_status           =   '0',
                        metatags_title_tagline_status   =   '0' , 
                        EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_CUSTOM_FIELDS=''
```

Comment: It looks like there is an undefined constant being used. Might be because of a different software version. Did you turn on notices?

Comment: What's the problem? You're inserting into a field that doesn't exist. That's pretty much it... Google is your friend https://www.google.com/search?q=zencart+EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_CUSTOM_FIELDS

Comment: Thanks for that. I did. I agree, found that the one I am copying from is an older version. I will upgrade it and do it again and report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is fine (although not SQL standard). See it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e61d8).

Maybe you have two different versions of the product? On the new destination the column `EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_CUSTOM_FIELDS` does not exist.